# MySql command line with auto-complete

Tags: windows, gratis, mysql

I am looking for free a Windows executable (not Java, Python, Ruby, etc...) Mysql command line/shell/console with autocomplete.

It should autocomplete keywords (`sel<tab>` becomes `select`, `ins<tab>` becomes `insert`, etc), table names and columns.

Comment: The column name autocomplete won't be able to function until you specify what table(s) you're selecting from in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: Does it work in Windows?

Comment: Actually, I just tested it in windows, and the column name will autocomplete when you prefix it with the table name.

Comment: That sounds awkward, if it can't autocomplete the table name :-(  better than nothing, I suppose, if I copy/paste the table name. Does it work for keywords? E.g `sel<tab> becomes select`?

Comment: It does autocomplete table names; just not column names, unless you prefix them with the table name. E.g. if you have the table `users` and the field `name`, it won't autocomplete `name`; but it can autocomplete `u[tab].n[tab]`. And yes, it does autocomplete keywords.

Comment: Wait -  what are we talking about here? The MySql console? No autocmplete there. Are you talking of something else?

Comment: Sorry, I was referencing my answer, wherein one enables the mysql autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MySQL-Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). It has auto-complete option, but is not command line. Learn more about it [here](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two parts: Install cygwin with the mysql packages. This gives you the command line on windows. Then, enable the [mysql autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332338/autocompletion-in-the-mysql-command-line-client), either in a command line switch or in my.cnf.

Comment: While I would prefer not to install Cygwin just for this, it does seem a viable option, if I can find no altrernative,

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/devart-dbforge-studio-for-mysql-with-phr/240169414) at work. I can't test it here, owing to the company firewall, but will test it at home & get back. It looks like it answers my requirements.

> The Devart team has announced the new release of dbForge Studio for
>   MySQL v 6.3 with new features related to SQL code completion and
>   formatting, data import and export, data comparison, data
>   synchronization, and reporting.
>
> The list of new features includes Phrase Completion so that the Code
>   Completion function suggests not only separate keywords and object
>   names, but entire code phrases.